# Copy file from local folder to remote folder using java

Tags: java, file, http

Any idea how I can copy a File f (assume I was able to create the object) from a local folder to a remote destination that's as follows (assume my local laptop is with a vpn access and I can indeed access)?
Also, any formatting I'd need to do to the filename string below before creating a File from the location String (add %20 to spaces? replace / with //, etc)?
Thanks

http://a.b.com/c/somewhere here/filename.xlsx

Comment: You will need something that allows you to write, (s)FTP or scp into the webservers filesystem. Talking of Java you probably can create a webservice that receives POSTed files and stores them in the webserver

Answer (score 0):

Use Files and Path:

```
Path sourcePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("filename.xlsx");
Path destPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("http://a.b.etc.xlsx");
Files.copy(sourcePath, destPath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

As an aside, you say you can indeed access that destination file. Could you elaborate on how you manage to write to a file using http?